# How to use parameters that go to a script in html content?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

I am new to using Google script, but not completely new to programming.
I have looked at some examples and they generate HTML output like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmloutputFromFile('form.html') 
}
```

I would like to pass a parameter to my script to use that in the output.
I have gotten as far as that I can use this in the function:

```
var room= e.parameter.room
```

So when I execute my script with  url?room=test
I do get the value for that parameter.

But how can I use that variable room that I create in the HTML output and other code?

I have been looking at createTemplateFromFile but I am not getting anywhere.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction of what constructs and command to look at.

Comment: Look at pushing variables to template https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get query parameters client side[<sup>1</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url):

#### form.html

```
<script>
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  alert(location.parameter.room); //alerts "test" on loading  "url?room=test"
});
</script>
```

---

Alternatively, You can use scriplets to load html[<sup>2</sup>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates):

#### code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');
  temp.room = e.parameter.room;
  return temp.evaluate();
}
```

#### form.html:

```
<script>
    alert('<?=room?>'); //Printing scriplets
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this has helped me and I can now use the value in my parameter in my template. Greetings, Rob